# TypeError: element.sortable is not a function with angular-ui-sortable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, angular-ui-sortable

We are working with a Spring Boot Admin application, more specifically spring-boot-admin-server-ui. SBA library is shipped with a webpacked file called `dependencies.js`, which includes all the js libraries used by SBA.

We've added some custom scripts of a remote application (**over which we don't have control**) at the end of the `index.html`, right after the `dependencies.js` script tag. One of them (`vendor.js`) includes the `angular-ui-sortable` lib, which has some conflicts with `dependencies.js`, and causes the following error:

```
TypeError: element.sortable is not a function
    at Object.link (http://localhost:22081/admin/lib/msgui/vendor.js:72953:19)
    at http://localhost:22081/admin/dependencies.js:43:5652
    at http://localhost:22081/admin/dependencies.js:44:9993
    at $e (http://localhost:22081/admin/dependencies.js:44:10050)
    at h (http://localhost:22081/admin/dependencies.js:44:2501)
    at a (http://localhost:22081/admin/dependencies.js:43:30350)
    at a (http://localhost:22081/admin/dependencies.js:43:30367)
    at a (http://localhost:22081/admin/dependencies.js:43:30367)
    at h (http://localhost:22081/admin/dependencies.js:44:2445)
    at a (http://localhost:22081/admin/dependencies.js:43:30350) <ul id="fromList" class="links-container ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope" ui-sortable="nodesList" ng-model="availableNodes">
```

According to https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/issues/443, the different versions of JQuery could be the issue. Problem: we can't either modify the `dependencies.js` or the `vendor.js` files. So, the solution could be to reuse webpack, merge the scripts and resolve the conflict. But I don't know if it's possible. Have you got a solution/example of solution ?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44932576/jquery-ui-sortable-is-not-a-function-with-webpack