# jQuery UI $(...).sortable is not a function with WebPack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I believe I've set everything up correctly, but I'm getting an odd issue with Webpack.

Consider this simple `app.ts` file:

```
'use strict';

import $ = require('jquery');
import 'jquery-ui';

$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
});
```

Everything compiles fine, but when the site is run it complains that the `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function`. (`sortable` is a jQuery UI function).

Everything works fine when I instead link to a CDN hosted version of jQuery and jQuery UI, but it doesn't work when I use JS modules and Webpack. Why is this?

Why is the jQueryUI function `sortable()` not recognized?

Comment: Can you include the tslint.json? It is still unclear why you think that they are being compiled in that order.

Comment: Consider showing that in your question. Also include how you are compiling the code (TypeScript version and flags if you have any).

Comment: Do you use System.JS to load CommonJS modules ? See:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44929021/import-json-file-typescript-keeps-saying-cannot-find-module/44929550#44929550 If you use this order no longer becomes important the System.import resolves the require.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is that jQuery UI normally automatically pulls in the components it needs (which is why it works when it's linked via a CDN), but that doesn't work when it's imported as a module (like with Webpack).

Thankfully as of jQuery UI 1.11 you can manually pull in any extra components you need like so:

```
'use strict';

import $ = require('jquery');

require('jquery-ui');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable');
require('jquery-ui/ui/disable-selection');
```

etc.

Here's some [official documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/environments/amd/) explaining this further.

Comment: Thank you, I spent an hour trying to make jquery-ui works with TS and apparently this was the actual issue.

Answer (score 4):

you use incorrect ES6 import syntax, but it still wouldn't work if it was right.
`sortable` is not recognized because `$` isn't avaliable inside `jquery-ui` module.

**This solution isn't optimized because you import whole `jquery-ui`.**

`npm install --save jquery-ui-bundle`

**index.js**

```
'use strict';

import 'jquery-ui-bundle';

$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
});
```

**webpack**

```
  plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          $: 'jquery',
          jQuery: 'jquery',
          'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
          'window.$': 'jquery'
      })
  ]
```

Comment: `jquery-ui-bundle` does not seems to be maintained by the jquery-ui team. Furthermore the advantages of importing modules with webpack are not present when importing a complete bundle.

Comment: Yes, it's the easiest, but not the best way.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is merely a summary of two helpfull other answers : 
[Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34003565/4306452), [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42465244/4306452)

First, better to know that `jquery-ui-dist` and `jquery-ui-bundle` are not maintained by the jquery-ui team. So you will probably want to avoid using it. Nevertheless, from jquery-ui version 1.11 you can require/import AMD, and from version 1.12 you can use the official package with npm.

**Solution 1 :**
The preferred way to go is then to import part of jquery-ui such as :

```
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable';
```

The only drawback is that if you previously used `import 'jquery-ui'`, you now have to import each modules you want to use specifically. But this is better as it will only bundle the imports you really need.

Check the [1.11 AMD support documentation](https://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.11/#amd-support) and the [1.12 npm documentation](https://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.12/#official-package-on-npm) on their site.

**Solution 2 :**
But, if for any reason you want to use a single global jquery-ui import, you will have to adapt your webpack config:

First, ensure webpack knows about the jquery aliases :

```
...
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      '$':'jquery',
      'jQuery':'jquery',
      'window.jQuery':'jquery',
      'global.jQuery': 'jquery'
    }),
...
```

Then, help webpack resolving the jquery-ui js location :

```
resolve : {
    alias: {
      // bind version of jquery-ui
      "jquery-ui": "jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js",      
      // bind to modules;
      modules: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules"),
```

Then, ensure the jquery-ui is loaded as soon as possible (maybe during startup ?)

```
var $ = require("jquery"),
        require("jquery-ui");
```

If you want to use a theme with jquery-ui, you will have to setup the css-loader and file-loader accordingly. (Don't forget to install those loaders):

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
      { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loader:"file" },
```

And below you imports of jquery and jquery-ui just add :

```
import 'modules/jquery-ui/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css';
import 'modules/jquery-ui/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.theme.css';
```