# jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__(...).sortable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jquery-ui

> ERROR jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__(...).sortable is not a
> function TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__(...).sortable
> is not a function
> at addSortable (https://dev.kore.ai/static/js/bundle.js:1784:62)
> at Object.onSectionDragStart (https://dev.kore.ai/static/js/bundle.js:1775:5)
> at onDragStart (https://dev.kore.ai/static/js/bundle.js:9875:160)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (https://dev.kore.ai/static/js/bundle.js:134152:18)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (https://dev.kore.ai/static/js/bundle.js:134196:20)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (https://dev.kore.ai/static/js/bundle.js:134253:35)
> at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (https://dev.kore.ai/static/js/bundle.js:134267:29)
> at executeDispatch (https://dev.kore.ai/static/js/bundle.js:138410:7)
> at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (https://dev.kore.ai/static/js/bundle.js:138436:11)
> at processDispatchQueue (https://dev.kore.ai/static/js/bundle.js:138447:9)

I am getting this error when

```
$(".gr-section-list").sortable({
            cursor: "grabbing",
            cursorAt: { left: -5, top: 5 },
            helper: 'clone',
            scroll: true,
            zIndex: 9999,
            start: (e, ui) => {

            },
            stop: (e, ui) => {
               
            },
        });
```

I have included jquery and jquery-ui in project but still I am getting this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery UI $(...).sortable is not a function with WebPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44932576/jquery-ui-sortable-is-not-a-function-with-webpack)